# How to Bulk Insert all Text file from a Folder?

Tags: sql

I have a multiple text file and I want to insert it on a #Temp table. 
Below is the sample script I made.

```
create table #Temp
(
   Column1 Varchar(max), 
   Column2 Varchar(max), 
   Column2 Varchar(max)
)

BULK INSERT #Temp FROM 'C:\File1.txt' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =',')

select * from #Temp
drop table #Temp
```

Since my path is for File1.txt only, how can I insert the rest? *.txt doesn't work for me.

Please help!

Regards,

Comment: Tag the dbms used, to get better attention and better answers - faster!

Answer (score 0):

Use the information in the above link to get all the files with a required filemask from a folder.

[How to list files inside a folder with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559846/how-to-list-files-inside-a-folder-with-sql-server)

Then you can store this list and pass one filename at a time to BULK INSERT command thru variable.

Hope this information helps.