# SQL BULK INSERT FROM CSV From a Folder

Tags: sql-server, loops, bulkinsert

I have this SQL command which will be used in a stored procedure and will be scheduled:

```
BULK INSERT Test101.dbo.Test102
FROM 'C:\Bulk\samp.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

It works well but what I want to do is to process all the `.csv` files from a folder (let's say `Bulk` folder) automatically. I mean, the user doesn't have to define the exact location with filename instead the stored procedure will process all the `.CSV` file from that folder and ignore the other files if there were.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Wil, please tag stuff correctly. MSFT sql server is `sql-server`, keep `mysql` off of it or clean that tag up and out in the future.

Comment: @Drew, Sorry about that. can you help me with this?

Comment: Years ago, but not at the moment. Sorry. Wait for the pros to show up :p

Comment: @WilDech Dech A solution that I have in mind will need elevated rights and access xp_cmdshell or some other MSSQL system function ... let me know if that will work for you

Comment: @objectNotFound That will do. Actually I have this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076309/import-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-from-a-folder
I just don't know how to make that work for me.

Comment: @WilDech that was exactly what I had in mind ... what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @objectNotFound I haven't tried that actually. 'cause I don't know how to implement that to mine. Sorry, I'm new to programming

Comment: @objectNotFound I have tried it now and it's not getting error but it says Access is denied. in the WHICHFILE column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11560496/2628302  try running just the sp_configure commands listed in that post (its a one time config change only) and then try that code again and see if you can get past the access denied issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these to make sure you have the right permissions and settings to do xp_cmdshell

One Time config change to enable here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131503/2628302

```
--To Test if that worked run these commands. There should be no errors and should return list of files under c:\
declare @files table (ID int IDENTITY, FileName varchar(500))
insert into @files execute xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\ /b'
select * from @files
```

--if no errors then proceed to create this SP as shown below. This is the one that does all the work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_BulkInsAllFilesInDirectory
AS
BEGIN
    --a table to hold filenames 
    Declare   @ALLFILENAMES as TABLE (WHICHPATH VARCHAR(255),WHICHFILE varchar(255))

    --some variables
    declare @filename varchar(255),
            @path     varchar(255),
            @sql      varchar(8000),
            @cmd      varchar(1000)


    --get the list of files to process:
    SET @path = 'C:\Bulk\'
    SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @path + '*.csv /b'
    INSERT INTO  @ALLFILENAMES(WHICHFILE)
    EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
    UPDATE @ALLFILENAMES SET WHICHPATH = @path where WHICHPATH is null


    --cursor loop
    declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM @ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE like '%.csv%'
    open c1
    fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
    While @@fetch_status <> -1
      begin
          --bulk insert won't take a variable name, so make a sql and execute it instead:
           set @sql = 'BULK INSERT Temp FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
               + '     WITH ( 
                       FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
                       ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
                       FIRSTROW = 2 
                    ) '
        print @sql
        exec (@sql)

        fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
      end
    close c1
    deallocate c1

END
```

--- TEST it by running it like so (start with just one csv file in C:\BULK\ directory. If it works for one it will most likely work for more than one file.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_BulkInsAllFilesInDirectory
```

see if there are errors. Leave a message here and I will check tomorrow. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried this but the following errors occur:

Comment: BULK INSERT PH_ProdCost.dbo.ProdCost FROM 'C:\Test\po.csv'      WITH ( 
                       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
                       ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
                       FIRSTROW = 2 
                    ) 
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: @WilDech you are most welcome. For the benefit of others Please edit your question and explain how you got over that error (Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK").