# List All Folder Subdirectories in Parent Folder with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, directory, sql-server-2016

How do I list All Subdirectory Folders within a Folder in SQL Server 2016?

Say I have a Folder called Test
`Foldertest` which contains

```
FolderA
FolderB
FolderC
```

I want to list all three Folders, and ignore all individual files.

Currently trying to utilize 
`EXEC xp_dirtree`

[How to list files inside a folder with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559846/how-to-list-files-inside-a-folder-with-sql-server)

Comment: I would suggest that using sql server to parse directories is the wrong tool for the job. It is designed to query data, not parse the OS directory structure. This should be done in your app or possibly with CLR.

Comment: This is for a data warehouse, not an OLTP Application by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

```
Declare @Table table (SubDir varchar(500),Depth int)

Insert into @Table
EXEC xp_dirtree  'C:\Foldertest',1,0

Select * From @Table
```