# Dynamically restore database in sql server with multiple files

Tags: t-sql

Dynamically restore database in SQL server with multiple files.
I have a requirement to restore database from multiple files as below.But how to write a query to get files which are available in that specific folder because no.of files today is 3 tomorrow it may raises to 4.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514168/12354911) answer may help for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system defined extended stored procedure called `xp_dirtree`. You won't find any microsoft documentation on this - it is unsupported. It's easy, it's built in, but use it at your own risk. It could theoretically disappear when you upgrade your SQL install.

Alternatively, you can use [`xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but the general advice to disable this extended procedure in `sys.configurations`, because it is inherently dangerous.

You could write your own CLR stored procedure. Jonathan Kehayias has an [excellent article on this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/trading-in-xp_cmdshell-for-sqlclr-part-1-list-directory-contents).

You could write your own application or service to manage your backups.

Or you could buy one of the several products which manage this kind of thing. A recommendation on which one is not really on topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah I knew to get filenames from that folder.My question is how to automate these restoring processing.I need script to get dynamical disk statements based on the file count.