# SQL Server EXEC xp_cmdshell INSERT TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add records to the table using the xp_cmdshell command as in the example query below. Can you help me on how to do this?

```sql
INSERT INTO SDS_TBL_MF_FILE_LOCATION_CONTROL (CustomerID,CustomerName,FileName) 
SELECT '1','TestCustomerName' ,EXECUTE xp_cmdshell 'dir C:\Sales\Text\TestFolder\/b'
```

Comment: You *can't* use `xp_cmdshell` as part of a `SELECT` statement; you'll need to consume the data from `xp_cmdshell` first, perhaps into a temporary table, and then `INSERT` that data into the table. Though, honestly, I'm not a fan of using `xp_cmdshell` as a crutch like this; if you want to get details of directories in a location, use something like Powershell to consume and `INSERT` that data into SQL Server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list files inside a folder with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559846/how-to-list-files-inside-a-folder-with-sql-server)

Comment: As you have discovered, tsql has no formal support for accessing the file system in this manner. That is a clue that you should think very differently about the goal. A securely designed system will likely not allow the database engine to access any random directory as well.